# Classic ASP - Subtracting numbers but keep leading zeros

Tags: asp-classic

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I have a number, it could be 004 or 010 ... I would like to subtract it by 1 and keep the leading zero.

Everytime i try to subtract, it always takes away the leading zero.

for instance

```
004 - 1
```

This always ends up as just

```
3
```

But i would like it to be

```
003
```

Having said that if i have 010 and i subtract 1 i would like it to be 009

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Do your calculations with integers then change to a string to display them. then concatenate "0" or "00" where needed  eg

```
c = a - b

displayvalue = cstr(c)

if c < 100 then
displayvalue = "0" & cstr(c)
end if

if c < 10 then
displayvalue = "00" & cstr(c)
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Continue doing the math as you are but include some padding 0's using the Right and String functions.

```
Dim a, b
a = 003
b = 1

Right(String(3,"0") + cstr(a-b), 3)
```